# Condition is false but code inside the if statement executed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have this code:

```
        setInterval (function(){
            var r_width=$(document).width();
            if(r_width>650){
                alert(r_width);
                $("#game, #gms").hover(function() {
                    $("#gms").stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
                }, function() {
                    $("#gms").stop(true, true).delay(10).fadeOut(400);
                });
            }
        }, 1000);
```

**Condition is true:**

When document width is bigger than 650 alert is shown and the code .hover is executed. 
**Condition is false:**

However when document width is less than 650 alert isn't shown but the code is executed.

Why when condition is false the code is executed?

Comment: you have attached hover listener to #game and #gms. Once you attach it. It is there unless you detach them.

Comment: Why on earth would you put an event handler inside an interval? I'm not even sure how to answer this, what would be the point of this code ?

Comment: Is it possible that some other section of code is running and not this?  Add a console.log() after the alert to test it.

Comment: You aren't detaching the event listeners in the `else` block. This is the wrong way to do this though. You should be listening for [`$(window).resize`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/).

Comment: If the condition is false, the code won't be executed. So if the code is executed the condition is not false. I would start with console log of `r_width` before the if statement to see if it really is bigger then 650 and has the same data type.

Comment: Do you realize every second you are adding another event? Means you should have tons of alerts

Answer (score 2):

The code isn't executed, but you've put an event handler inside the interval, and the event handler isn't removed when the function fires again, it stays, and you just keeping adding more event handlers every second.

Add the event handler **once**, and do the checks inside the event handler

```
$("#game, #gms").hover(function() {
    if ( $(document).width() > 650 )
        $("#gms").stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
    if ( $(document).width() > 650 )
        $("#gms").stop(true, true).delay(10).fadeOut(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if the condition `r_width>650` evaluates true at least one time (that code is executed every one second as you put it in a `setInterval`) the `hover` listener is attached to the elements with selector `#game` and `#gms`.

Then every time the hover event is triggered the code of the callback is executed despite of the value of `r_width`